# I am new to vue.js iam trying to post and get the value in a crose platform but iam getting this error

Tags: php, node.js, vue.js

I am trying a cors-platform API call for a post and get method to register the data in vue js

Note:
  The API call should be a cross-platform

but I am facing this issue

Response to a preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin  is therefore not allowed access.

I tried this solution "[CORS issue: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316443/cors-issue-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested)" but still am getting this error. I don't know how to solve this

```
Here is my code:-

methods:{
signup () {
  console.log("hi i got the response");
  this.$http.get("http://otherSite.com",{
    userName:this.register.username,
    Email:this.register.email,
    Password:this.register.password,
 }).then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: personally, I use this set up: `const cors = require('cors'); app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    credentials: true
}));` Make sure you install cors first and put that code into your server file, changing the port of course as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate cors. Here is a cors implementation: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

```
let cors = require('cors')

let app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Just use it and it will work.